# Jenkins console output flooded with [DEBUG] http-outgoing log entries

Tags: jenkins, logging, continuous-integration, verbosity

We have a build job where the console output shows many strange messages like below, so we cannot load a full log and have to remove the `-X` option in the build configuration to get rid of them. I think it happened after I upgraded the Jenkins version.

Any idea of what might be causing this?

```
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> "j[0x5]q4/J[0x18]^di[0x86][0xbf]C_[0xd6]G[0x1d] 
[0xd4][0x7][0xf3][0xc7][0x14][0xdf][0x8d][0xe1][0x13][0xd8]$y|#[0x1e][0xbf] 
[0xe6][0x81]<[0xca][0x6][0xa1]~j[0x81]3[0xbc][0x98][0xd1][0x83][0xa7] 
[0xc5]8[0xfa]>[0xd9]edZ[0xb2][0xc][0xe0][0x5][0xab][0xf3][0x1a]M[0xb3][0xe7] 
[0x1][0xf4][\n]"
[DEBUG] http-outgoing-0 >> "[0xcd][0x9d][0x86]Zjp[0xb4][0x8d][0x87] 
[0x8f]cn[0xe7][0xab]oL.[0xb2]}[0x86][0xf8]D[0x87][0xba][0x9d][0xcc]j[0x15] 
[0xa4][0xe6]![0x9f]_BBC[0xbf]j[0xab]Rl[0x10][0x92][0xc5])[0xb2][0xc5]i[0xc2]
```

Comment: Maybe it's because of the build tool?

Comment: I think so, we did not meet this issue before

Comment: Is there any exception reported just before that message? (as in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34774)

Comment: @VonC That Jenkins issue is totally unrelated to this problem. These are DEBUG messages (no exception), while JENKINS-34774 involves SEVERE messages (thrown exceptions).

Comment: Do you use the *cobertura* and/or *artifactory* Jenkins plugins? Could you provide a full list of the plugins you have enabled (other than the defaults)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this exact problem right around the same time (April 2018), and found that it was being triggered by Artifactory plugin 2.15.0 (and later). For over a year, I had left that plugin downgraded in order to avoid having DEBUG logging in my build logs. Although this worked for me (until I was forced to upgrade last week due to an incompatibility with new versions of Artifactory), it is possible that a different plugin or jar file in your classpath is causing the problem in your case.

After spending an entire weekend troubleshooting this problem, I finally found the underlying cause in my build environment.

The important points are:

- This is a problem with the classpath of the build process (e.g., Ant).
- This is not a configuration problem with Jenkins.
- This cannot be fixed via the project configuration.
- The trigger (a Jenkins or plugin update) is not necessarily the underlying cause of the DEBUG logs.
- When this problem is triggered, there may be multiple causes, which makes this problem very difficult to troubleshoot.

**The Dormant Problem**

---

In my case, the underlying cause of the DEBUG logging was that I had **cobertura-2.1.1.jar** in my test dependencies, which contains a **logback.xml** file and also brings **logback-classic.jar** in as a dependency (widely regarded as a mistake, see [Issue 2](https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/issues/2), [Issue 14](https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/issues/14), [Issue 36](https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/issues/36)). The **logback.xml** file, when found in the classpath, overrides any other logback settings in Jenkins (and the project being built). However, since logback was not the logging framework selected by Apache Commons Logging (JCL), this log setting had never been triggered.

**The Trigger**

---

Upgrading the Artifactory plugin from 2.14.0 to 2.15.0 switched its logging from: **commons-logging-1.1.1.jar** (**log4j-1.2.17.jar**) to: **jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar** (**slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar**). FYI, [log4j 1.x](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) uses a default root logging level of DEBUG, while [log4j 2.x](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) uses a global logging level of ERROR, which *may* be an entirely different source of DEBUG logging (but not in my case). My build environment (ant) was supplying log4j 2.10.0 and logback on the classpath, which served only to confound my testing by producing inconsistent results depending on which plugins were running within the build process.

When using Artifactory plugin v2.15.0+, the logging framework switches to logback, which gives the **logback.xml** file in **cobertura-2.1.1.jar** permission to set the root log level to DEBUG, forcing all of the subsequent parts of the build process to record at the DEBUG level. This includes wire-logging for *Apache Commons HttpClient*, which produces **http-outgoing-0** (serialized hexadecimal *and* interleaved Base64 encoded content from every HTTP/S message - as you show in your question). Even for a small project, recording a single PUT of a JAR file in this way will increase both the build time and the size of your build logs by several orders of magnitude (this is what I was experiencing in my build environment), which can easily cripple your entire Jenkins server. This is a huge problem, and as you can see from the Cobertura GitHub issues above, even though it is an easy fix, no steps have been taken to produce a fixed version in four years.

**The Fix**

---

To fix this, I had to make several changes on my Jenkins server:

- Replace **logback-classic.jar** and **logback-core.jar** with **slf4j-simple-1.7.26.jar** in my **.ant/lib** folder (this is the classpath that Ant uses when building and testing my projects). This change prevents the use of logback at all in Ant (therefore any **logback.xml** file in the classpath becomes irrelevant), while still allowing your build to perform logging over the SLF4J API (via **slf4j-simple**).
- Remove any dependencies on redundant logging versions (e.g., don't include both **commons-logging-1.1.1** and **commons-logging-1.2** in the classpath). This is especially important if using log4j, where version 1.1 defaulted to DEBUG, and version 1.2 defaulted to ERROR. You never know which underlying framework JCL will choose, so you want to give it as few options as possible.
- Finally, in order for the test environment to match the Ant environment, I adjusted the dependencies of *all* of my projects to *specifically exclude* **logback-classic** (I use Ivy for dependency resolution, so maven or gradle will have a different syntax):

  ```
  <dependency org="net.sourceforge.cobertura" name="cobertura" rev="latest.release" conf="test->default">
    <exclude org="org.apache.ant" />
    <exclude name="jaxen" />
    <exclude name="jetty" />
    <exclude name="jetty-util" />
    <exclude name="servlet-api-2.5" />
    <exclude name="logback-classic" /> <!-- IMPORTANT -->
  </dependency>
  ```

For reference, my *broken* **.ant/lib** folder contained these logging-related jar files (2 possible sources of DEBUG logs):

- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar *(redundant JCL version, not certain which was used)*
- commons-logging-1.2.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar *(logging framework used by new artifactory plugin)*
- logback-classic-1.0.13.jar *(logging framework included from cobertura-2.1.1)*
- logback-core-1.0.13.jar

while my *fixed* **.ant/lib** folder contains the following logging jars:

- commons-logging-1.2.jar *(now the only available JCL version)*
- slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar *(now the only available logging framework)*
- slf4j-simple-1.7.26.jar *(now the only SLF4J implementation)*

In my fixed Ant classpath, **commons-logging-1.2** can only select the SLF4J API (or JUL), and only a single SLF4J implementation is available (**slf4j-simple**).

**TL;DR**

---

For three years, Cobertura 2.1.1 was telling logback to *"DEBUG All the Things!"*, but nobody was listening until a new version of the Artifactory plugin changed the JCL version and brought along an SLF4J implementation that allowed logback to be selected as the "best available" logging framework. When the JCL was introduced to logback, logback took Cobertura's advice and threw a party in my build logs. This can be prevented by removing logback from the environment and supplying a well-behaved logging framework for the JCL and SLF4J API (such as **slf4j-simple**).

Answer (score 0):

So i stumbled on this issue recently, in my case this was caused by setting **-X**  flag in maven during the build phase. Someone set this flag and forgot to remove it. Its an old issue but maybe this information will be useful to someone.